# Bigquery case with multiple conditions resulting in schema error

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a query that has a case statement with multiple conditions on different columns.

`CASE
WHEN X = 'A' AND not Y is null THEN 1
END AS metric1`

The query runs and I get a result as expected, but when trying to access the destination table, I get this error:

`Unable to find table:`

`The schema for this table was automatically detected. If the schema was not correctly detected, you can re-run the load job with an adjusted schema.`

Comment: You have a low rate. Important on SO, you have to mark accepted answers by using the tick on the left of the posted answer, below the voting. This will increase your rate. See how this works by visinting this link: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235

Comment: Does this happen multiple times? Can you recreate the issue with a public query and dataset?

Comment: I cannot repro this problem. Pentium10's suggestion about public query and dataset would be helpful.

Comment: I was also not able to reproduce this using the public datasets.  This looks like an issue with my dataset, however, I am not sure why as the schema works fine prior to creating the case.